# Is there a list of usual comments?

Tags: feature-request, comments, low-quality-posts, question-quality, answer-quality

Is there any official list of useful and formal comments that can be used for frequent cases (e.g., this question/answer is `___` because `___`, or, welcome to SO ...etc), if there isn't an official one, then where do users who post such comments get them from?

Comment: Essentially *[Repository of useful pro-forma comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136609)*  (cross site).